# Setting variable types from CSV

Tags: c#, linq

```
var csv =
    from line in File.ReadAllLines("C:/file.csv")
    let customerRecord = line.Split(',')
    select new Customer()
        {
            contactID = customerRecord[0],
            surveyDate = customerRecord[1],
            project = customerRecord[2],
            projectCode = customerRecord[3]
        };

public class Customer
    {
        public string contactID { get; set; }
        public string surveyDate { get; set; }
        public string project { get; set; }
        public string projectCode { get; set; }
    }
```

I'd like to be able to read the `surveyDate` as a `DateTime` in order to compare it with other `DateTime` fields I'm joining to the csv file.

I've tried just setting `surveyDate` as Date.Time in the class, and I've tried converting it in the select statement, but both fail with the following error:

> FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

I do have to work with the csv file, so I can't add the data to sql server.

> contactID,responseDate,project,projectID
>   1,6/4/2009,0-3 months,1
>   2,6/11/2009,0-3 months,1

Comment: -1 _"but both fail"_ What does that mean, where's that code?

Comment: What you have in **customerRecord[1]**

Comment: contactID,responseDate,project,projectID
1,6/4/2009,0-3 months,1
2,6/11/2009,0-3 months,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right... Because you can never know what the input will be from the CSV you can't always try and implicitly convert the string to a DateTime and because you want to do the convert of a string within the select a way to do this is an extension method.

```
  public static class StringExtensions
  {
    public static DateTime TryParseDate(this string strToParse)
    {
      DateTime dt = new DateTime();
      DateTime.TryParse(strToParse, out dt);
      return dt;
    }
  }
```

Then when you want to convert in the select do it like this:

```
  var csv = from line in File.ReadAllLines("C:/file.csv")
            let customerRecord = line.Split(',')
            select new Customer()
                {
                  contactID = customerRecord[0],
                  surveyDate = customerRecord[1].TryParseDate(),
                  project = customerRecord[2],
                  projectCode = customerRecord[3]
                };
```

You have your own method. Hope this helps and works for you.

The string you want to parse will be passed to the method and then you can handle it and return a valid date time, handling incorrect inputs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

See this link for an explanation

Comment: Thank you for the excellent walk-through.  This works, and I understand why I need to specify how to handle the dates.

Comment: Sorry Luke. User error on my part.  I'm learning the ropes here.  It works.

Comment: Not a problem - Just checking if you'd encountered a new problem which you needed help with:) Glad it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse it when reading as well as changing the type. I'm not sure how you tried it in the first place. Also, use `DateTime.ParseExact` if you know the format.

```
var csv =
    from line in File.ReadAllLines("C:/file.csv")
    let customerRecord = line.Split(',')
    select new Customer()
        {
            contactID = customerRecord[0],
            surveyDate = DateTime.Parse(customerRecord[1]),
            project = customerRecord[2],
            projectCode = customerRecord[3]
        };

public class Customer
{
    public string contactID { get; set; }
    public DateTime surveyDate { get; set; }
    public string project { get; set; }
    public string projectCode { get; set; }
}
```

Judging by the error you just posted, I think it's probably double-quoted. Try trimming the quotes:

```
DateTime.Parse(customerRecord[1].Trim('"'))
```

Comment: This is exactly as I tried it the first time.  Within the csv file the date is stored as 6/4/2009 as an example.  Without the DateTime.Parse code I get an error:  Cannot execute text selection: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: When is 6/4/2009? Is it in April, or in June? (And was that from looking at it in text or something like Excel or Calc?)

Comment: For this set of data it is US dates, but I also have UK dates in another file.  This example is June 4, 2009.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried just setting surveyDate as Date.Time in the class, and I've tried converting it in the select statement, but both fail.

Well you need to do both. You need to change the property type (ideally fixing the naming at the same time to follow conventions) *and* change where you're setting it, probably using `DateTime.ParseExact`, specifying the format and probably the invariant culture.

(I'm assuming you know the format of the date in the file - I would *strongly* advise you to use `DateTime.ParseExact` rather than just letting the framework try various formats until it finds one which works.)

EDIT: Now that we've seen the file, it looks like you'd want *either*

```
DateTime.ParseExact(text, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(text, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

... but we can't tell which, as we don't know whether "6/4/2009" means April 6th or June 4th.

Comment: FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

Comment: @JimMelichar: Well that suggests you've used the wrong format. As you haven't told us what the values look like or what you've tried, it's rather hard to help further...

Comment: Jim, Jon is correct here and that's not the error I'd expect. What format is this date in? (Guarantee you my answer won't work either, but knowing that format would let either of us Jon's figure it out).

Comment: Okay, two votes for using DateTime.ParseExact.  I'll give this a try.  Thank you for the help.  I'm just starting to use linq and I appreciate the help.

Comment: If I crack it open in excel, it's stored as a Date in the format 6/9/2009

Comment: @JimMelichar: Open it in a *text editor*. If it's quoted, well, there's your problem... or one problem.

Comment: And if it is `6/9/2009` does that mean the 6th of September or the 9th of June? If it's from Excel, it could well be something like `40396` as it sometimes stores dates and times as number of days from 1899-01-30 (or some time close to that, I don't recall it exactly).

Comment: @JimMelichar: See my edit for two possible options. We can't tell which is the right one though.

Comment: As a follow up, there were no quotes when opened in a text editor.

Comment: @JonSkeet How is CultureInfo.InvariantCulture implemented when working in linqpad so that I can use it with the DateTime.ParseExact statement you suggested above?

Comment: @JimMelichar: What do you mean by "how is it implemented"? It's just a static property. Maybe you need to add a using directive somehow (System.Globalization).

Comment: @JonSkeet No worries, the issue is that I don't understand how to use directives in linqpad to test this method.  Previously I've written all my C# in VS, and all my SQL based queries in linqpad, which is why I likely confused you.  I'll work it out.  Thank you.

Comment: @JimMelichar: You may be able to just write System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, as a temporary measure.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just needed a more recent version of linqpad that worked with the directives.  I'll test this and report back.  Thank you.

Comment: @JonSkeet This throws the "string was not recognized as a valid DateTime" error.  Which is confusing because the TryParseDate method in the answer below worked just fine and it appears to be a less exact method.  This is the line of code I inserted:  surveyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(customerRecord[1], "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),

Answer (score 0):

After changing `Customer` so that `SurveyDate` is a `DateTime` then:

```
select new Customer()
    {
        contactID = customerRecord[0],
        surveyDate = DateTime.Parse(customerRecord[1]),
        project = customerRecord[2],
        projectCode = customerRecord[3]
    };
```

You may need to use forms of `Parse` or `ParseExact` that take a format string, to be sure of the correct result. That format string depends on the format used in the file.

Alternatively, you could create a `Parse` static method on Customer:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string contactID { get; set; }
    public DateTime surveyDate { get; set; }
    public string project { get; set; }
    public string projectCode { get; set; }
    public static Customer Parse(string line)
    {
       var parts = line.Split(',');
       return new Customer{
         contactID = parts[0],
         surveyDate = DateTime.Parse(customerRecord[1]),
         project = customerRecord[2],
         projectCode = customerRecord[3]
      };
};
```

Then:

```
var csv =
  from line in File.ReadLines("C:/file.csv")
  select Customer.Parse(line);
```

This has an advantage if obtaining a `Customer` from such a formatted string happens more than once in your code. It needlessly fills `Customer` with cruft if this is the only place you do it. Note I favour `ReadLines` over `ReadAllLines` to get a line at a time rather than read the whole thing before starting do produce customers.

Incidentally, .NET conventions favour capitals on property names. `SurveyDate` rather than `surveyDate` etc.

Comment: Jon - I appreciate the notes on proper convention on names.  Understood on your note about Customer, I think that likely will be the only place I'll call it.  Thank you for the tips.  I'm sure I'll be back.

Answer (score -1):

You should convert your `customerRecord[1]` string to a `DateTime`.

```
var csv =
    from line in File.ReadAllLines("C:/file.csv")
    let customerRecord = line.Split(',')
    select new Customer()
        {
            contactID = customerRecord[0],
            surveyDate = DateTime.Parse(customerRecord[1]),
            project = customerRecord[2],
            projectCode = customerRecord[3]
        };

public class Customer
    {
        public string contactID { get; set; }
        public DateTime surveyDate { get; set; }
        public string project { get; set; }
        public string projectCode { get; set; }
    }
```